# Percorrer todos os nós json

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe5

Tenho o seguinte arquivo Json.

```js
{"symbol":"KYCT","status":"ACTIVE"},{"symbol":"UNDA","status":"ACTIVE"},
{"symbol":"QUIA","status":"ACTIVE"}
```

Tenho a seguinte rotina para leitura que carrega este arquivo :

```
JsonValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(lResponse.DataString);
```

Até ai tudo bem .

Assim eu consigo pegar os valores.

```
JsonValue.GetValue<string>('symbols[0].symbol')
JsonValue.GetValue<string>('symbols[0].status')
```

Porém acontece que a posição `[0]`, é a primeira posição `Symbol` que tem no arquivo, e vou precisar percorrer todos os symbols para pegar a propriedade `status`, porém não imagino a forma que eu poderia percorrer este aquivo texto, analisando todos nós.

Dei uma pesquisada mas não consegui encontrar algo, podem me ajudar por favor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nas versões mais modernas do Delphi esta muito simples trabalhar com Json, mas em versões menores que o XE8 é complicado, muita gambiarra é necessária para uma simples utilização nativa.

Nativa podemos utilizar algo como:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  vMensagem: string;
  vJsonValue: TJSONArray;
begin
  vMensagem := '{"symbol":"KYCT","status":"ACTIVE"},{"symbol":"UNDA","status":"ACTIVE"},{"symbol":"QUIA","status":"ACTIVE"}';

  vJsonValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue('[' + vMensagem + ']') as TJSONArray;

  for i := 0 to Pred(vJsonValue.Size) do
    ShowMessage(TJSONObject(vJsonValue.Get(i)).Get('symbol').JsonValue.Value);
end;
```

Observe que tivemos mudanças, na hora de consumir o objeto tivemos que converte-lo para um array.

```
vJsonValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue('[' + vMensagem + ']') as TJSONArray;
```

Em seguida bastou percorre-lo acessando cada um dos objetos:

```
vJsonValue.Get(i)
```

Aqui o `.Get` nos devolve um `JsonValue`, então, somos obrigados a transforma-lo em um  `JSONObject` e acessar através do `.Get` que agora é diferente e nos devolve um `JsonPair`. Sabendo que é um par de dados pedimos o valor do par informando seu nome:

```
.Get('symbol').JsonValue.Value
```

No XE10 em diante a classe `Data.DBXJSON` esta descontinuada, agora possuímos uma classe dedicada `System.Json` muito mais completa e enxuta.

Comment: Obrigado, fiz aqui e deu tudo certo !!!

Comment: Marque a resposta como correta, assim ajuda em futuras pesquisas

Answer (score 1):

Você pode percorrer o JSON usando um "for in" como mostra abaixo:

```
const
  JSON = '[{"symbol":"KYCT","status":"ACTIVE"},{"symbol":"UNDA","status":"ACTIVE"},{"symbol":"QUIA","status":"ACTIVE"}]';
var
  LJSONValue: TJSONValue;
  LJSONArray: TJSONArray;
begin
  LJSONArray := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSON) as TJSONArray;
  try
    for LJSONValue in LJSONArray do
      ShowMessage(LJSONValue.GetValue<string>('symbol'));
  finally
    LJSONArray.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Completando, se você tiver algo como:

```js
{"users":[{"name":"NOM1","code":1122334},{"name":"NOME2","code":1234}]}
```

Para pegar os valores de users, além da resposta do Junior Moreira, adicionando colchetes no início e fim da string json e percorrendo os valores, pode fazer:

```
if vJSONPair.JsonString.Value = 'users' then
   result := vJSONPair.ToString
```

Porém, o retorno disso será:

```js
"users":[{"name":"NOM1","code":1122334},{"name":"NOME2","code":1234}]
```

Então, eu faço:

```
copy(vJSONPair.ToString, 9, length(vJSONPair.ToString)- 8)
```

Porque sei o retorno de antemão.